# Unable to pass context to the home view

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to add a `like` button that changes to `unlike` when the User clicks on it, however the button isn't changing because I am unable to pass the context to the `home.html` file. I know the logic i used will throw an error as the `get_object_or_404()` will not receive an id from the server however if I pass an argument `id` to the `home()` function it will also throw an error as the server doesn't provide an `id` to the page. I'm sorry for asking a question related to logic and not concepts but I haven't been able to understand which concept could i use here

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Blog
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect



def home(request):
    post=get_object_or_404(Blog,id=id)
    context={
    'posts':Blog.objects.all(),
    'is_liked':post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()
    }
    return render(request,'blog-home',context)
def like_post(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    is_liked=False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked=False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked=True
    context={
    'is_liked':is_liked
    }   
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.get_absolute_url(blog_id))

def post_detail(request, id):
    post=get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id)

    context={
        'post':post,
        'is_liked': post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists(),
        }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',context)








def check_liked(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    is_liked=False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.User.id).exists():
        is_liked=True
    else:
        is_liked=False
    context={
    'is_liked':is_liked
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(blog_id):
        return reverse('post-detail',args=[str(blog_id)])
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.home,name='blog-home'),
path('<int:blog_id>/like/', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
path('post/<int:id>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
]
```

home.html

```
{% block content %}
    {% for post in blogs %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <h2>{{ post.author }}</h2>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <form action="{% url 'is_liked' %}">
              {% if is_liked %}
                  <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Unlike</button>
              {% else %}
                  <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
              {% endif %}
              </form>
            </form>
          </div>
        </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

post_detail.html

```
<article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <h2>{{ post.author }}</h2>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if is_liked %}

                <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Unlike</button>

          {% else %}

                <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
          {% endif %}
        </form>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: what this line does     return render(request,'blog-home',context)

Comment: and what is 'blog-home'

Comment: Can you share the code of `blog/post_detail.html`?

Comment: Why are you using the form with action="{% url 'is_liked' %}"? I don't see a url with that name in your url pattern.

Comment: @c.grey it is an error it should be home.html I was tinkering around and forgot to change it back before posting the code sorry

Comment: @Sanip I had made that url then deleted it as it was not doing what i wanted the form didn't cause any errors so it didn't draw my attention thanks for pointing out

Comment: @ruddra added it to the code you can check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for getting the functionality you want. In your home.html, you can make changes as:

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in blogs %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <h2>{{ post.author }}</h2>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
          <button type='button' onclick="change_status(this)" id="{{post.id}}" name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
      </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

<script>
function change_status($this){
var request_data = $this.id;
console.log("data: " + request_data);
$.post({
    url: "url that leads to your view",//url to like_post in your case(pass the request_data value in the url as the url needs the post id)
    data : { request_data: request_data},
    success : function(json) {
        if(data.is_liked == True){ //perform a check of returned data(dont know actual implementation but you can google it)
        document.getElementByName('blog_id').innerHTML = "Unlike"   }
        else{
             document.getElementByName('blog_id').innerHTML = "Like"  
        }
    }
})}
</script>
```

The functionality can be achieved by something like this but you may need to perform some changes in it.

Comment: I've tried this but it just changes the button but doesn't add or remove likes

Comment: Changes are not been viewed in database or just in the html?

Comment: in the database

Comment: You need to properly specify the url in the ajax script so that the view changing the likes number can be changed. Look at the terminal to check if the required view function is being called upon button click. If not, then properly configure the url in the ajax script.